# Don't make some fields searchable when using query_string or term/terms in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Having this mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/testindex?pretty=true' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "items": {
       "dynamic": "strict",
       "properties" : {
            "title" : { "type": "string" },
            "body" : { "type": "string" },
            "tags" : { "type": "string" }
}}}}'
```

I add two simple `items`:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/testindex/items/1' -d '{
  "title": "This is a test title",
  "body" : "This is the body of the java",
  "tags" : "csharp"
}'


curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/testindex/items/2' -d '{
  "title": "Another text title",
  "body": "My body is great and Im super handsome",
  "tags" : ["cplusplus", "python", "java"]
}'
```

If I search the string `java`:

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/testindex/items/_search?q=java&pretty=true'`

... it will match both items. The first item will match on the `body` and the other one on the `tags`.

How can I avoid to search in some fields? In the example I dont know it to match with the field `tags`. But I want to maintain `tags` indexed as I use them for getting aggregations.

I know I can do it using this:

```
{
  "query" : {
     "query_string": {
          "query": "java AND -tags:java"           
     }},
     "_source" : {
          "exclude" : ["*.tags"]
     }
}'
```

But is there any other more elegant way, like putting something in the mapping?

PS: My searches are always `query_strings` and `term` / `terms` and I'm using ES 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can specify [fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_multi_field) option if you only want to match against certain fields

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "fields" : ["body"],
        "query" : "java"
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

You could use the `"include_in_all": false` param inside mapping. Check the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/include-in-all.html). Query string query defaults to `_all` so you can add `"include_in_all": false` to all the fields in which you **don't** want match and after that this query would only look in *body* field

```
{
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "java"
        }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: I know, as I stated on the question I know there are ways not to search on those fields, but I would like to know if there's a way to specify that on the mapping.